# Build a url with URI.js

Tags: javascript, url

I am using URI.js in my project to parse and build URLs, however the URI.js documention doesn't give enough example for me to follow, when I tried to build a URL like so:

```
// expect output: Admin.aspx?controller=login&action=submit

var url = URI.build({
    path: "Admin.aspx",
    query: {
        controller: "login",
        action: "submit"
    }
});

// actual result: Admin.aspx
```

How can I use URI.js correctly to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears you want  `URI.buildQuery()` to pass object to to create your query string

Comment: It means I have to write tons of codes with couple of functions to build a simple URL, I'd rather manually write a URL string to achive my goal. URI.js isn't that convenient for me.

Comment: All you need is wrap object shown with that function...I believe. Have never used the library. But shows `query` value being string in docs

Comment: var url = URI.build({path: "Admin.aspx", query: { URI.buildQuery({controller: "login",action: "submit"})}}); Too much code for this.

Comment: `query: URI.buildQuery( { controller: "login", action: "submit" } )`. There's a second argument ...didn't read what it was for

Comment: WHat's with accepting other answer that came in long after I showed you what was needed and all they had to do was copy what was in my comments?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var url = URI.build({
    path: "Admin.aspx",
    query: URI.buildQuery( {
        controller: "login",
        action: "submit"
    })
});
```